# Drools integration with Android

Tags: android, jboss, drools, rule-engine

I'm trying to integrate Drools in one of my Applications. Due to lack of documentation available online I'm facing so many issues. Earlier I was struggling with the dependency issues but later on I resolved this using following gradle commands.

```
compile 'org.kie:kie-api:6.1.0.Final'
compile 'org.drools:drools-core:6.1.0.Final'
compile 'org.drools:drools-compiler:6.1.0.Final'
compile files('libs/drools-android-6.5.0.Final.jar')
compile files('libs/janino-3.0.7.jar')
```

Now the problem is to load drl files in which the actual rules are written. So as per the references I got to know that we need to use **KieServices** for this. So I have a **myrule.drl** file in the storage and using this service I'm trying to load the rule file but getting  errors while doing the same. Sharing my code for better understanding.

```
  KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
            KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

            // for each DRL file, referenced by a plain old path name:
            String fileName = "myrule.drl";
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/Data/"+fileName);
            kfs.write( "src/main/resources/myrule.drl",
                    kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis ) );

            KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
            Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
            if( results.hasMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
                System.out.println( results.getMessages() );
                throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" );
            }

            KieContainer kieContainer =
                    kieServices.newKieContainer( kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId() );
```

Here I'm getting exception while instantiating **KieBuilder** object. The exception is as follows -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate object for class 'org.drools.android.DexPackageClassLoader' with constructor public org.drools.android.DexPackageClassLoader(org.drools.core.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData,java.lang.ClassLoader)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.core.util.ClassUtils.instantiateObject(ClassUtils.java:272)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.core.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData.makeClassLoader(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:618)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.core.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData.onAdd(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:243)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.<init>(JavaDialect.java:187)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration.newDialect(JavaDialectConfiguration.java:91)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.buildDialectRegistry(KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl.java:392)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageRegistry.<init>(PackageRegistry.java:55)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.newPackage(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1571)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.initPackageRegistry(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1044)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.createPackageRegistry(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1015)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.initPackageRegistries(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:297)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackages(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:116)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:105)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieModule.java:244)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:64)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:230)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:198)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at com.example.admin23.droolstest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:128)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
06-05 09:57:25.059 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.core.util.ClassUtils.instantiateObject(ClassUtils.java:270)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     ... 29 more
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.android.MultiDexClassLoader.<init>(MultiDexClassLoader.java:70)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     at org.drools.android.DexPackageClassLoader.<init>(DexPackageClassLoader.java:44)
06-05 09:57:25.069 21955-21955/com.example.admin23.droolstest W/System.err:     ... 31 more
```

One more thing here. if I'm changing my dependencies in the app gradle from 6.5.0.final to 6.1.0 final then I'm getting the following exception.

```
: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                    Process: com.example.admin23.droolstest, PID: 30886
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field UTF8_CHARSET of type Ljava/nio/charset/Charset; in class Lorg/drools/core/util/IoUtils; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.drools.core.util.IoUtils' appears in /data/app/com.example.admin23.droolstest-2/base.apk:classes2.dex)
                                                                                        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.getOrGeneratePomXml(KieBuilderImpl.java:495)
                                                                                        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:464)
                                                                                        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.getPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:448)
                                                                                        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.init(KieBuilderImpl.java:134)
                                                                                        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:169)
                                                                                        at com.example.admin23.droolstest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:143)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Can anyone help me to sort this out as I have no idea what can I do to resolve this. Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a _dedicated_ chapter in the documentation called "Chapter 14. Android Integration", it could help as a reference. Or could you kindly highlight which part of Drools API allegedly reported as "lacking" from the same doc? Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: @tarilabs Thanks for the reply but I have already checked this documentation. Theoretically it helps but implementation wise there is not much stuff present.

Comment: without a concrete indication of what is missing and just a generic "there is not much stuff", is difficult for others to help, or to amend corrections as needed. Anyway, I just wanted to hopefully provide an helpful reference with examples (as from the doc mentioned in my prev comment)

Comment: Thanks for the help and I have already mentioned the error I'm getting while creating KieBuilder Object. I need to resolve this to load my drl file.